# Insert page break every nth row

Tags: libreoffice-calc, page-break, libreoffice-basic

I have been trying to insert page breaks every n rows in LibreOffice Calc. I have tried a macro which doesn't seem to work:

```
Sub PAGE_BREAK() 
  For MY_ROWS = 50 To Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row Step 50
     ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Range("A" & MY_ROWS)
  Next MY_ROWS
End Sub
```

I get a sub-procedure or function not defined error for the above code.

Any ideas how I can do this more easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting page breaks in LibreOffice Calc sheets works a little bit different than in MS Office VBA. With LibreOffice Basic (or OpenOffice.org Basic), you insert a (horizontal) page break by setting the [row's `IsStartOfNewPage` property](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/table/TableRow.html#IsStartOfNewPage) to `true`. To access every `n`th row, you could simply use `ThisComponent.Sheets(0).Row(n)`.

So, combining this in a LibreOffice Basic macro, the result could look like this:

```vba
sub pagebreak
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem define variables
Dim Sheet As Object
Dim Cell As Object   

Sheet = ThisComponent.Sheets(0)

for i = 10 to 100 Step 10
    Sheet.Rows(i).IsStartOfNewPage = true
next i

end sub
```

This macro just inserts a manual page break after each 10th row (notice that the first row is `Rows(0)`, so `Rows(10)` is row # 11), up to row 101 of the current sheet. You can easily adjust that code to fit your needs (max. number of rows etc).

Comment: Thank you very much :-) Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

**not working for me**. `Sch` is iterating over the rows, should move an "automatic" page break back to element 1 of a list. `SP` is the column where the list is enumerated. **Overall** this snippet should avoid *orphan* list elements.

`

```
    if theSheet.Rows(Sch).IsStartOfNewPage = True then
    msgbox "pgBrk in " & Sch
    theSheet.getcellbyposition(RegDatPos+1,Sch).cellbackcolor=rgb(0,200,0) :REM color is set as expected...
    theSheet.getcellbyposition(RegDatPos+1,Sch).value=1
    schpgPos=theSheet.getcellbyposition(SP,Sch).value
    if schpgPos<>1 then
        theSheet.Rows(Sch).IsStartOfNewPage = false
        back=1
        do while theSheet.getcellbyposition(SP,Sch-back).value<>1
            back=back+1
        loop
        msgbox "Back for " & back
        theSheet.Rows(Sch-back).IsStartOfNewPage = True
        theSheet.getcellbyposition(RegDatPos+2,Sch-back).value=1
            theSheet.getcellbyposition(RegDatPos,Sch-back).cellbackcolor=rgb(222, 111, 150)
        endif
    endif
```

`